# How to replace Swift substring with an Un-Equal substring by using location?

Tags: swift, string, swift4

Can’t use occurrence of pattern as text can change at any instance.

```
var originalString = "Hi there <un>"
var stringToPut = "Some Amazing Name"
// Change string between 10th index and 13th to the following.
var requiredString = "Hi there <Some Amazing Name>"
```

This is very easy for just 1 character or when the length of the replacing string is same. But breaks when the substrings are unequal in length as the length of parent string changes and exact location references cannot be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this works.

```
let originalString = "Hi there <un>"

let subString = "Some Amazing Name"

let characters = Array(originalString)

let firstPart = characters[0..<9]

let lastPart = characters[13..<characters.count]

let finaString = ("\(String(firstPart))\(subString)\(String(lastPart))")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `replaceSubrange`:

```
var originalString = "Hi there <un>"
var stringToPut = "Some Amazing Name"
// Change string between 10th index and 13th to the following.
var requiredString = "Hi there <Some Amazing Name>"

let startIndex = originalString.index(originalString.startIndex, offsetBy: 9)
let endIndex = originalString.index(originalString.startIndex, offsetBy: 12)
originalString.replaceSubrange(startIndex...endIndex, with: "Some Amazing Name") // "Hi there Some Amazing Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format of `<un>` the simplest method would be:

`let newString = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "<un>", with: stringToPut, options: .literal, range: nil)`